# flip and rotate a color image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, colors

How do I flip a color image (RGB) in MATLAB?
The `fliplr` does not seem to work without losing the color contents, as it only deals with 2D.

As well, the `imrotate` may not rotate color images.

Comment: I have no problems rotating color images with `imrotate` (R2013a).

Comment: `fliplr(img)` is equivalent to `flip(img, 2)`.
And it deal not only with 2D arrays. For multidimensional arrays, `fliplr` operates on the planes formed by the first and second dimensions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html) will work for N-D matrices, whereas the functions [`flipud`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) and [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) only work for 2-D matrices:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');     %# Load a sample image
imgMirror = flipdim(img,2);      %# Flips the columns, making a mirror image
imgUpsideDown = flipdim(img,1);  %# Flips the rows, making an upside-down image
```

**NOTE:** In more recent versions of MATLAB (R2013b and newer), the function [`flip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) is now recommended instead of [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html).

Comment: Please, replace `flipdim()` by `flip()`, since the former is not recommended because of various reasons.

Answer (score 22):

An example:

```
I = imread('onion.png');
I2 = I(:,end:-1:1,:);           %# horizontal flip
I3 = I(end:-1:1,:,:);           %# vertical flip
I4 = I(end:-1:1,end:-1:1,:);    %# horizontal+vertical flip

subplot(2,2,1), imshow(I)
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(I2)
subplot(2,2,3), imshow(I3)
subplot(2,2,4), imshow(I4)
```

[image]

Comment: I also like it better this way.

Comment: yep :) Besides others had already shown how to use `flipdim` and its new replacement `flip`.

Comment: @Amro New thread here about flipping `imagesc` + `axes` in an integrated approach http://stackoverflow.com/q/39923300/54964 - - I am not confident that your approach can maintain `axes`.

Answer (score 2):

`imrotate` rotates color images
B = IMROTATE(A,ANGLE) rotates image A by ANGLE degrees in a 
    counterclockwise direction around its center point.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late, but since flipdim is now depreciated, other answers are not valid anymore. You could use [flip](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html), or do it in other, smart way:

```
I = imread('onion.png');

% flip left-right, or up-down:

Iflipud = flip(I, 1)
Ifliplr = flip(I, 2)

% or:
Iflipud = I(size(I,1):-1:1,:,:);
Ifliplr = I(:,size(I,1):-1:1,:);

% flip both left-right, and up-down, stupid way:
Iflipboth = I(size(I,1):-1:1,size(I,1):-1:1,:);

% flip both left-right, and up-down, smart way:):
Iflipboth = imrotate(I, 180)
```

As already pointed, imrotate deals with color images as well as with greyscale.