# How can I turn an image over in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to **turn over an image in Matlab** (I mean, if the picture looks right then it should be looking at the left). How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This can be called a horizontal flip. Or a horizontal reflection etc

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: [flip and rotate a color image in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010113/flip-and-rotate-a-color-image-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flip the image before displaying with [FLIPLR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fliplr.html)

```
imshow(fliplr(image))
```