# How to flip image with handles in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have an image with handles lines and plots. I want to flip image with lines and plots(handles). Could is it be possible in matlab ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [**`flip`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html),  [**`fliplr`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) and [**`flipud`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flip and rotate a color image in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010113/flip-and-rotate-a-color-image-in-matlab)

Comment: Do you mean that you have a plot and you want to flip the plot? Look into `set(gca, 'YDir', 'Reverse')` or `axis ij`

Comment: good. Thanks. It works now.